How is the Joint Probability Density Function derived under the Multinational Production model?
I was reading the paper "Trade, Multinational Production, and the Gains from Openness" by Ramondo and Rodríguez-Clare.
In the paper （see Appendix A）, they define the following function for the probability that country (l) is the least-cost location to serve market (n) with technology from country (i):
$$
F_1\left(z, a_{n 2 i} z, \ldots, a_{n I i} z ; T_i\right) = \left(\left(c_{1 i}^g d_{n 1}\right)^\theta\left(\widetilde{c}_{n i}^g\right)^{-\theta}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}} T_i \theta z^{-\theta-1} \exp \left[-\left(c_{1 i}^g d_{n 1}\right)^\theta T_i\left(\widetilde{c}_{n i}^g\right)^{-\theta} z^{-\theta}\right],
$$
where $F_1$ relates to the minimization of costs across countries, with $a_{n j i}$ representing cost ratios, and the productivity draws assumed to follow a multivariate Frechet distribution.
Could someone explain how the function $F_1$ is derived from the basic assumptions? Any clarification on the steps from the productivity distribution to this formula would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!
